# Fitting GAMM model in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, fitting

when fitting GAMM with R, I would like to know why when the smooth function is linear, the confidence interval is zero around the middle (the dotted lines are crossing each other at the middle)

Answer (score 5):

It is due to the default for argument `'seWithMean'` in `plot.gam()`, which is `FALSE`. This plots confidence intervals purely for the centred smooth function only, and there is no uncertainty at 0. If we add in the uncertainty in the mean then you get the more familiar confidence interval.

Here's an example, but using `gam()` rather than `gamm()` as it shows the same issue:

```
## dummy data:
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10 + rnorm(10))
plot(y ~ x, data = dat)

## load mgcv and fit an AM to the dummy data
require(mgcv)
mod <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = dat, method = "ML")
```

The default plot shows the credible intervals as you describe:

```
plot(mod)
```

whilst more natural credible intervals are given by

```
plot(mod, seWithMean = TRUE)
```